# ngRoute loads only template on refresh

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, pug, ngroute

I have a project using nodejs with express & pug in the backend, and AngularJS with ngroute on the frontend. The way it used to work was:

1. I enter website, it loads index.html (with angular stuff) and then 
   /home(with content created with pug) as a view.
2. When i choose to enter another document, angular requests it from
   express, and server fills it with pug (eg. /users), angular loads it 
   into view leaving menu,etc. untouched

It used to work very well, until i decided to remove the # from address (using this: https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag). Now when i reload the page somewhere else than home, it loads only raw view, without stuff provided by index.html. I thought about redirecting to home, but it wont be always what i need. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: did you tried $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); last in config?

Comment: yes, also included $loactionProvider to the config